# How to add new div when hitting enter key in contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, angular

I am building an Angular 7 app. In this app I have a page with a div that got contenteditable set to true. When a user press the enter key a new div is added to the editor/div right after the div that was focused when the user hit enter. Unfortunately this code (see below) only works if the div got at least one character. This is not good because I would like to use a fake placeholder in the div and not actual characters.

How can I change my code below to work even if the div is empty?

```
insertBlock($event) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    const selection = window.getSelection();
    const selectedElement = selection.anchorNode.parentNode;
    const block = document.createElement('div');
    block.innerHTML = 'Type slash for commands';
    block.className = 'ce-block';
    block.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Type slash for commands');
    this.editor.insertBefore(block, selectedElement.nextSibling);
    selection.collapse(block.firstChild, block.textContent.length);
  }
```

The HTML looks like this (I am using a directive to listen to editor events):

```
<div class="ce-container" blockeditor [menu]="menu">
 <div class="ce-menu" contenteditable="false" #menu>Menu</div>
 <div class="ce-block" placeholder="Type slash for commands"></div>
</div>
```

The idea is to build a so called block editor (like for example Notion.so).

Thank you!

Comment: Please add a minimal reproducible example like Stackblitz

Answer (score 0):

I've had a go at this, not sure if what you need but have a look at [StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sl8zqu)

Uses [Renderer2](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2) to create and add new divs and give them an event listener that calls the same handler to add more from the new ones.

Uses keyup.enter as the event to trigger the handler.

Behaviour:

- Start with empty div, tab into it and hit enter. New div created
  after it.
- Tab to new div and hit enter. New div created after this
  one.
- Go back to a previous div, hit enter - new div created after
  this div and before next.

The main function in .ts is:

```
    onPress(item: HTMLElement) {
//Create div element with contenteditable attrbute. This is the new div
         let div = this.renderer.createElement('div');
         this.renderer.setAttribute(div, 'contenteditable','');
//Add enter key press listener that calls this same function so gives add functionality to new divs
          this.renderer.listen(div, 'keyup.enter', (event) => { this.onPress(event.target) });

//Attaches the new div to the DOM
         if (item.nextSibling != null)
         {
           this.renderer.insertBefore(item.parentElement,div,item.nextSibling);
         }
         else
         {
           this.renderer.appendChild(item.parentElement, div);
         }
       }
```

html template:

```
<div contenteditable (keyup.enter)="onPress($event.target)"></div>
```